# CentOS 7.x iptables

Tags: linux, networking, centos, iptables

I have manually edited the /etc/sysconfig/iptables file in my CentOs 7.x installation , I have two entries and two processes running at the respective ports.

I am able to telnet/access port 2181 but not port 8081 , only if I stop iptables service that I am able to access port 8081 , is there anything obviously wrong that I am doing ?Please note that the same iptables config works in CentOS 6.x

Thanks.

```
#TOMCAT PORT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8081 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#ZOO KEEPER PORT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2181 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7 uses firewalld.  You will need to modify and/or disable that to get your desired results.